# Need to add a new df as a row in existing dataframe by keeping the index similar in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Cit':[1,3,4,8,6], 'Hou':[15,10,20,45,70]}).set_index(pd.Series([0,1,2,8,4]))
```

and another one

```
df2= pd.DataFrame({'Cit':[6,1], 'Hou':[55,29]}).set_index(pd.Series([1,3]))
```

i need to insert a new data frame to the old and the resulting data frame should be reindexed but consist of all datas in both dataframes.

i want:

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame({'Cit':[1,6,3,4,1,8,6], 'Hou':[15,55,10,20,29,45,70]}).set_index(pd.Series([0,1,2,8,4,5,6]))
```

Comment: Your df and df2 lines of code aren't actually dataframes. Are these supposed to be creating dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

Seems @Hima Santhosh has add mistakenly added 8 instead of 3.
Try this,

```
pd.concat([df2,df]).sort_index(axis = 0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: ya, it has sense.

Comment: `pd.concat([df2,df]).sort_index(ignore_index=True)`